# Optimizing bilinear interpolation

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, image, sse

I have spent countless hours trying to speed up my bilinear interpolation up. I even tried implementing an SSE version (a double version and a float version), but that was even slower than this version.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I wrote this under VS2010 and it is intended to be called from MATLAB as a MEX function (thus the minus one subtraction in interp2_mx because indexing in MATLAB is from 1:end as opposed to 0:end-1).

My function interp2 requires a T (intended float/double type) pointer to Z (mz by nz matrix) and interpolates the points in XI and YI into ZI (which are all the same size mi by ni).

```
template <typename T>
__forceinline void interp2_mx(const T& x, const T& y,
                          const T* z,
                          const int32_t& n,
                          const int32_t& mm2,
                          const int32_t& nm2,
                          T& val,
                          const T& extrapval = T(0))
{
    int64_t xp = (int64_t)(x) - 1;      // adjust for MATLAB indexing
    int64_t yp = (int64_t)(y) - 1;
    if (xp < 0 || xp > nm2 || yp < 0 || yp > mm2)
    {
        val = extrapval;
    }
    else
    {
    const T* line = z + yp * n + xp;
    T xf = x - (int64_t)(x);   // get decimal portion     
    T yf = y - (int64_t)(y);
    T x1mf = (T)1 - xf;        
    T y1mf = (T)1 - yf;

    T v00 = x1mf * y1mf * (*(line));
    T v01 = xf * y1mf * (*(line + 1));     
    T v10 = x1mf * yf * (*(line + n));     
    T v11 = xf * yf * (*(line + n + 1));   
    val = v00 + v01 + v10 + v11;
    }
} 

template <typename T>
void interp2(const T* z,
         const int32_t& mz, const int32_t& nz,
         const T* xi, const T* yi,
         const int32_t& mi, const int32_t& ni,
         T* zi,
         const T& extrapval = T(0))
{
const int32_t nzm2 = nz - 2;
const int32_t mzm2 = mz - 2;    
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int m = 0; m < mi; ++m)
{        
    T* line_zi = zi + m * ni;    
    const T* x = xi + m * ni;
    const T* y = yi + m * ni;
    for (int n = 0; n < ni; ++n, ++x, ++y, ++line_zi)
    {
        interp2_mx((*x), (*y), z, nz, mzm2, nzm2, (*line_zi));            
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you have profiled the code, where is the the biggest time loss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Profile It!

As suggested in the comments, you should profile the code to see where the slowdown is.

### Algebra Is Your Friend

One small suggestion I can offer is some algebraic improvements.

A linear interpolation between `a` and `b` can be formulated like this:

```
result = a * interp + b * (1 - interp);
```

That's 2 adds and 2 multiplies. You can use some algebra to reduce that to:

```
result = interp * (a - b) + b;
```

which is 2 adds and 1 multiply. Doing that also removes the need to calculate `x1mf` and `y1mf`. So your inner loop would become:

```
T xf = x - (int64_t)(x);   // get decimal portion     
T yf = y - (int64_t)(y);

T a = *line;
T b = *(line + 1);
T top = xf * (a - b) + b;
T c = *(line + n);
T d = *(line + n + 1);
T bottom = xf * (c - d) + d;
val = yf * (top - bottom) + bottom;
```

That takes you from 8 multiplies to 3, but from 9 adds to 10. So that's likely from 17 instructions to 13.

There are a few more optimizations you can do:

You're subtracting 1 from `x` and `y` every time through the loop. You could calculate the values with the 1 already subtracted out in `interp2()` rather than in `interp2_mx()`:

```
for (int m = 0; m < mi; ++m)
{        
    T* line_zi = zi + m * ni;    
    const T* x = xi + m * ni - 1; // <- Do this here instead of on every loop iteration!
    const T* y = yi + m * ni - 1; // <- Same here
```

You might also have luck by keeping track of a pointer to the next input pixel just incrementing it instead of calculating `line` every time through the loop, too.

### Naming

It would be nice if you could pick more easily understandable names for your functions and variables. Why is this called `interp2()`? What is `interp1()`? You should name it `bilinearInterp()` or something obvious like that. And what does `interp2_mx()` mean?

Using `x` and `y` to represent horizontal and vertical offsets is fine. Those are well-established traditions. But you're naming the start of your image `z` which is really weird. `z` is usually reserved for depth, at least when used with `x` and `y`. That makes your code very confusing to read.

Likewise, `mz` and `nz` are confusing, too. And even worse in `iterp2_mx()`, `mm2` and `nm2` are not only confusing but easy to mix up! `mz` and `nz` should be something like `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` (or `matrixWidth` and `matrixHeight`, or `inputWidth` and `inputHeight`), and the other variables and arguments should be appropriately named as well.

Why do `xi` and `yi` have an `i` in their names? That makes them look like integers, but they're declared as type `T`, which you say will likely be float or double.

### Errors

Looking at your error handling, I'm not convinced it's sufficient. You check if `xp` is less than `0` or greater than `nm2`, and the same for `yp`. But what happens when `xp` exactly equals `nm2`? `line` ends up pointing to the last pixel in a line. But then you calculate `line + 1`. That gets you the first element of the next row. And for `yp`, it means reading a row that doesn't exist when `yp` equals `mm2`.